No peer connection config when running node command
I am using pixel streaming ue5 setup with linux. Starting cirrus server with node causes 'NoPeerConnectionConfig' error and Disconnected(1006) when trying to connect to the website game version.
I think NoPeerConnectionConfig is webrct and javascript related. Can someone guide me where i should look at getting the cirrus server working? Or maybe where i can create the peer connection config?
Running with custom flags like --publicIp
